# Convert list items to defined data type

Tags: python, list, types, type-conversion

I'm rather new to python and I'm not sure how to do the following.

I have a list `foo` containing metadata and measurement values for a certain plot. For example, a plotID, survey date, initials of surveyors, several measurement values and a categorical variable.

```
foo= ['plot001', '01-01-2013', 'XX', '10', '12.5', '0.65', 'A']
```

Because these data are read from a .txt, all list items are strings. My question is: *how do I convert each list item to the approporiate datatype?*. I can make a list with the desired data types:

```
dType= ['str', 'str', 'str', 'int', 'float', 'float', 'float', 'str']
```

It would be nice if I could apply each item in `dType` as function to the matching element in `foo` as such:

```
out= [str(foo[0]), str(foo[1]), str(foo[2]), int(foo[3]), float(foo[4]), float(foo[5]), float(foo[6]), str(foo[7])]
```

but I'm sure there must be a better solution! Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Yes, the suggestion of @roippi works very fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And @John1024 also suggested this, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of a list of strings, make `dType` a list of builtin factories:

```
dType= [str, str, str, int, float, float, str]
```

(you had an extra `float` that I removed)

Then just use `zip`:

```
[t(x) for t,x in zip(dType,foo)]
Out[6]: ['plot001', '01-01-2013', 'XX', 10, 12.5, 0.65, 'A']
```

**Bonus:** you could even get fancy and make your own factory functions and apply them in the same manner with `functools.partial`.  Say, if you wanted that date to turn into a `datetime` object:

```
def datetime_factory(format,s):
    from datetime import datetime
    return datetime.strptime(s,format)

from functools import partial

dType= [str, partial(datetime_factory,'%d-%m-%Y'), str, int, float, float, str]

[t(x) for t,x in zip(dType,foo)]
Out[29]: ['plot001', datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'XX', 10, 12.5, 0.65, 'A']
```

(making our own factory `def` was needed here since `partial` only allows you to partially apply the *leftmost* arguments, and `strptime` requires the string-to-be-formatted first)

Answer (score 2):

```
foo= ['plot001', '01-01-2013', 'XX', '10', '12.5', '0.65', 'A']
fnlist= [str, str, str, int, float, float, str]
out = [fn(v) for fn, v in zip(fnlist, foo)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`ast.literal_eval` could be helpful:

```
>>> import ast
>>> def evaluate(x):
...     try:
...         return ast.literal_eval(x)
...     except (ValueError,SyntaxError):
...         return x
... 
>>> map(evaluate, foo)
['plot001', '01-01-2013', 'XX', 10, 12.5, 0.65, 'A']
```

Comment: this doesn't work for the dates.  I got ValueError: malformed string

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunataly, it doesn't seem to work for me. The error reads: `ValueError: malformed string`

Comment: yeah, you're right.  Hold on ... (that's what I get for answering and watching TV at the same time)

Comment: Yes, thanks, it works now! This is very nice because it elliminates the need for the `dTypes` list, so I can run this on any list containing any datatype. I'm not quite sure what the `ast.literal_eval` function exactly does though, would you care to elaborate on that?