# Translate python datatype to datatype of other language, using a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, arcgis, type-conversion, arcpy

this is a follow up of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587218/convert-list-items-to-defined-data-type). To reiterate, I have text file with metadata and measurement data of a given location. I want to write this data to spatial mapping software called ArcGIS for which I have to specify for each value in the list the data type *as defined in ArcGIS*. For example:

```
type("foo")
```

Gives `str` in Python, but is known as `text` in ArcGIS. So, I want to translate the datatype of every element in my list, to the appropriate datatype in ArcGIS. Something like this:

```
# This is the raw data that I want to write to ArcGIS
foo= ['plot001', '01-01-2013', 'XX', '10', '12.5', '0.65', 'A']
# The appropriate datatypes in Python are:
dt= [str, str, str, int, float, float, str]
# In ArcGIS, the datatypes should be:
dtArcGIS= ['text', 'text', 'text', 'short', 'float', 'float', 'text']
```

The question is: *how can I come from `dt` to `dtArcGIS`*? I was thinking of a `dictionary` as:

```
dtDict= dict{str:'text', int:'short', float:'float'}
```

But this gives a syntax error. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Remove `dict`, the curly braces already define it as a dict there's no need to tell Python to do it again, `dtDict= {str:'text', int:'short', float:'float'}`

Comment: `type('10')` is `str`, not `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two formats, just remove the `dict` like this

```
dtDict = {str:'text', int:'short', float:'float'}
```

And this is how you should convert the types

```
foo = ['plot001', '01-01-2013', 'XX', '10', '12.5', '0.65', 'A']
from ast import literal_eval

dt = []
for item in foo:
    try:
        dt.append(type(literal_eval(item)))
    except:
        dt.append(str)

dtDict = {str:'text', int:'short', float:'float'}
print map(dtDict.get, dt)
```

**Output**

```
['text', 'text', 'text', 'short', 'float', 'float', 'text']
```